# How to combine two files consecutively line after line

Tags: linux, bash, file, combinations

I have a text file (A.txt) with this these lines:

```
Aaaaaaa1
Aaaaaaa2
Aaaaaaa3
```

And other text file (B.txt) with this these lines:

```
Bbbbbbb1
Bbbbbbb2
Bbbbbbb3
```

I would like to combine A.txt and B.txt in other file (OUTCOME.txt) in this way:

```
Aaaaaaa1
Bbbbbbb1
Aaaaaaa2
Bbbbbbb2
Aaaaaaa3
Bbbbbbb3
```

How could I make this using bash shell in linux using **read, grep, echo, etc**?

Comment: paste file1  file 2|perl -pne "s/\s+/\n/g"                                         output                                                                  Aaaaaaa1
Bbbbbbb1
Aaaaaaa2
Bbbbbbb2
Aaaaaaa3
Bbbbbbb3

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
sed 'R b.txt' a.txt > OUTCOME.txt
```

Output to OUTCOME.txt:

```
Aaaaaaa1
Bbbbbbb1
Aaaaaaa2
Bbbbbbb2
Aaaaaaa3
Bbbbbbb3
```

Comment: Is it possible to merge these two files with echo? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know about that.

Answer (score 2):

Just `paste` is enough:

```
$ cat file1
Aaaaaaa1
Aaaaaaa2
Aaaaaaa3

$ cat file2
Bbbbbbb1
Bbbbbbb2
Bbbbbbb3


$ paste -d $'\n' file1 file2
Aaaaaaa1
Bbbbbbb1
Aaaaaaa2
Bbbbbbb2
Aaaaaaa3
Bbbbbbb3
```

Comment: I am doing exercises on using echo, how can I do it the exact same way, but using echo ?

Comment: @LenyNguyenová I don't think that you can get the same result easily with echo. You need to built some loops to read each line of each file and echo them alternativelly.

Answer (score 1):

Using `echo` and `read`:

```
while IFS= read -r line1 && IFS= read -ru3 line2; do
    echo "$line1"
    echo "$line2"
done < file1 3< file2
```

It's important that the second `read` uses a different file descriptor (`3` in this case).

Answer (score 0):

**`paste`** + **`awk`** solution (for your current input files):

```
paste a.txt b.txt | awk '{ print $1 ORS $2 }' > outcome.txt
```